# Flutter and Flutter.bat

Tags: flutter

I downloaded Flutter. I extracted the zip file in the src folder. When I opened it, there's no flutter.bat in the bin folder. Why is it missing??

I downloaded Flutter from the official website. I extracted it correctly. I opened it in the C:\src\ folder, but still, flutter.bat is not visible

Comment: Is there a `bin` folder? Are you following the instructions at https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows/desktop?

Comment: Yes, there is, and I followed the instructions on this site.

Answer (score 1):

If you downloaded the sdk from the official website, flutter.bat should be in the bin folder. There is no question about it.

Try adding the bin folder's path to your environment variables and run
**flutter doctor** from the cmd to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on which version you downloaded, maybe you downloaded not a Windows version!
Make sure that you downloaded Flutter from Stable channel (Windows)
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/archive?tab=windows